# If negative mass should exist, how would conservation of momentum work?

Tags: particle-physics, mass, energy-conservation, relativity, exotic-matter

Imagine that a particle with [negative mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass) has been discovered. It is known to obey both the equivalence principle and Newton's second law. This means that the particle is a subject to repulsive gravitational force from ordinary matter but also accelerates *towards* any repulsive force (resulting in the infamous [runaway motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass#Runaway_motion)).

Let's also say that the particle is able to interact with ordinary matter in the process of "nullification" (particless of oposite energy get close enough to each other and disappear). The problem is that this interaction would violate the conservation of momentum every time the two nullifying particles didn't have exactly identical velocities, which is practically never the case. And from what I understand, conservation of momentum is pretty important to all of our current theories.

My question is: Is there a mechanism that would allow for nullification but also leave the conservation of momentum unviolated and wouldn't break GR and QM? ([Energy conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_condition) may be broken.)

---

Originally I wanted to post this question to [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) but I decided it's too technical and generally better suited for this site, even if it's quite hypothetical.

---

**Edit**:

Nullification (as it is defined in the last paragraph of Wikipedia's [Runaway motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass#Runaway_motion)) is the interaction where particless of equal mass of opposite signs “cancel each other out”, completely disappearing from existence.

However, at least in classic physics, the probability that two particles with exactly opposite energy *and* momentum will find each other in finite time is zero. Therefore nullification would either never happen, or it would break some of the fundamental symmetries.

The answer should either show that this premise is wrong (eg. *“in QM the uncertainty of momentum is large enough to have the particles match exactly with a reasonable probability”*), propose an interaction that can cause the energy and momentum of the two particles to align by interactions with the outside world, or show that no such interaction is possible and therefore nullification cannot happen.

Comment: The conservation of momentum is not violated. Take two equal but opposite masses at rest and calculate the total momentum after they accelerate for some time: they would have equal but opposite momenta which would result in the same total momentum, i.e., zero. Of course, one of them would have opposite direction of velocity with respect to its momentum.

Comment: More on [negative mass](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%22negative+mass%22).

Comment: There isn't a relativistic counterpart to Newton's 2nd law.

Comment: @OktayDoğangün Momentum is conserved if you only consider the two particles, 
however if you add a third particle, say with a positive mass that hits the negative mass particle and they nullify a problem emerges. For simplicity, imagine the 3rd particle had extremely high velocity so it hits the negative mass particle before the forces have enough time to significantly change the velocities. In the reference frame of the 2 initial particles the total _p_ in the beginning is only the _p_ of the 3rd particle, after the nullification it is only the _p_ of the original positive mass particle.

Comment: @OktayDoğangün The particles would have to have the same direction of velocity, not opposite. $0 = p = p_1 + p_2 = v_1 m + v_2 (-m) \implies v_1 = v_2$. This is exactly what I say in the question. My problem with this is that you never find particles with the exact same velocity (at least in classical physics and GR, I don't know about QM) and therefore nullification would either never occur, or would violate the conservation of momentum.

Comment: @OktayDoğangün You should post answers as answers, not as comments.

Comment: @AaronStevens My comment does not answer the question. I tried to rectify the initial argument hoping OP to edit the question in a better way.

Comment: @m93a I didn't say two objects would have opposite velocities, I said ONE of the objects would have its direction of motion opposite to its OWN direction of momentum, which is what you have written yourself now.

Comment: @K.Kirilov Even if you include a third particle, still the total momentum is conserved. Suppose 1st particle is positive, 2nd is negative and third merged with the second so that only positive mass remained: $p_1+p_2+p_3 = p'_1+p$ where $p$ is the merged object's momentum from the annihilation. If the first object didn't interact with the other two at all, as you suggest, then the merged object that is constrained to have positive mass would have a velocity $v'=v_3-v_2$. If we constrain the merged object to have a negative mass then the velocity would be $v'=v_2-v_3$, i.e., just the opposite.

Comment: @OktayDoğangün There is no "merged object". Nullification is NOT annihilation. Annihilation releases the energy of the annihilated particles in the form of other particles. Perfect nullification does NOT. There is no resulting energy in any form, so there is no resulting particle to "carry" the momentum.

Comment: @K.Kirilov What does nullification mean here? Why two objects would "nullify" each other in the first place? In quantum field theory, two objects can not vanish completely unless they are anti particles of each other, and virtual pairs (which means they don't obey the equations of motion and have the equal but opposite energy-momentum).

Comment: @OktayDoğangün "Forward also coined a term, 'nullification', to describe what happens when ordinary matter and negative matter meet: they are expected to be able to cancel out or nullify each other's existence." a quote from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass#Runaway_motion . If a body has a negative mass that means it has a negative energy. Hypothetically if a positive mass particle and a negative mass particle with the same _absolute_ energy interact they should vanish completely. Even moreso than matter-antimater interaction, as the latter produces other matter-antimater pairs.

Comment: @K.Kirilov You said "with a higher momentum" in the previous comment but now you say with the same absolute energy. Even if two opoosite masses annihilate each other to perish completely, your argument about having an extra energy because of a third particle nullifying another still does not hold.

Comment: @OktayDoğangün Well, that is kind-of the point of this question. In real-world scenario you'd never get both total energy and total momentum of two particles to perfectly align. So either nullification would never happen, or there is some mechanism which would _cause_ energy and momentum to align by interacting with some other particles. The answer should either propose how such mechanism would work, or show that it's not possible.

Comment: @OktayDoğangün I imagined the third particle having higher velocity to make things simpler by ignoring the forces' influence. But having all three particles with the same high velocity would be even simpler. Imagine the third particle having velocity equal in magnitude, but perpendicular in direction to the others, so for the system before nullification $\vec p = \vec p_1 + \vec p_2 + \vec p_3 = \vec p_3$ because $\vec p_1$ and $\vec p_2$ are opposite. For the system after nullification you have $\vec p = \vec p_1$ because $\vec p_2$ and $\vec p_3$ don't exist. Should we move this to a chat?

Comment: @K.Kirilov I edited the question so now it's hopefully clear enough, therefore my comments can be moved to chat.